# Vertical text floating in bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created piece of code. In span class `mean-head` increase horizontally if the text of the span increase. I want to fix it's width for like 30 characters. After that text so go to new line.

[EXAMPLE FIEDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/JqN64/8/)

```
<span class="top-head"> Recommended URLs </span>
<div class="c1">   
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image"> 
            <img class="media-object" src="http://deathandtaxesmag.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Screen-Shot-2014-02-27-at-12.39.17-PM.png" >
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionContainer">
            <span class="main-head"> Mashable - Business </span>
            <span class="min-head">Title of link Title of link Title of link Title of link </span>
            <span class="subcont">
                    <span class="fa fa-retweet"> RT 100+ | </span> 
                    <span class="fa fa-twitter"> Tweet 100+</span> 
            </span>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help you?

```
span.min-head {
   display: block;
   font-size: 9px;
   margin-top: 1px;
   max-width: 130px;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Check the fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqN64/12/)

Answer (score 5):

Give fixed width for span class and add display block

```
.min-head { width:150px; display:block}
```